# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" in regression analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, error-handling

I recently started coding a little bit in Python.
Given following data:
[image]

I just want to make a simple calculation with following code:
[image]
Why do I get the error message when I only have integers and not defined strings? I hope you can help me.

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
df= quandl.get("FINRA/FORF_SYNVP", authtoken="sF7es4t9ozY6QjvZyL9M")
df=[['ShortVolume','TotalVolume']]
df['change_PCT']=(df['TotalVolume']-df['ShortVolume'])/df['ShortVolume']*100
df=df[['change_PCT','ShortVolume']]
print(df.head())
```

Edit: I've tried to type in the code using ´enter the code´ or the Ctrl+K combination but I always receive a error message...

Comment: It would be better if you post code here, not images. So others can copy it and see whats going on

Comment: Finally, I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning in the 5th line for `df` variable  a list, the error is legitim, just delete the 5th line

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I have seen that in my class mate's code it works fine. It was identical to mine. Is this due the Python 3 version?

Comment: No, it is not related to python version :)

Comment: i think  your class mates's just used `df[['ShortVolume','TotalVolume']]`